# Change clicked element (and all similar) to active / unactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I had a problem with the formulation of topic. Sorry if I duplicate question.

I have over a dozen containers with two childs.

```
<div class="some">
   <img id="1" class="pointer unactive" />
   <img id="2" class="pointer active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="3" class="pointer unactive" />
   <img id="4" class="pointer active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="5" class="pointer unactive" />
   <img id="6" class="pointer active" />
</div>
```

For example: When I click `img#3` I want to change other child (`#1, #3, #5`) to `active` and clicked element and similes (`#2, #4, #6`) to `unactive`.

Comment: Is it other child (`#1, #3, #4`) or other child (`#1, #3, #5`)? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us have another class that tells that all are `odd` and `even`:

```
<div class="some">
   <img id="1" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="2" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="3" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="4" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="5" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="6" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
```

Now, when `.even` is clicked, all the `even` will have `active` and all the `odd` will have `inactive` classes and vice-versa:

```
$(".even").click(function () {
  $(".even").addClass("active").removeClass("unactive");
  $(".odd").addClass("unactive").removeClass("active");
});
$(".odd").click(function () {
  $(".odd").addClass("active").removeClass("unactive");
  $(".even").addClass("unactive").removeClass("active");
});
```

> ***Note:*** Please do not use `id` values starting with a number.

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".even").click(function () {
    $(".even").addClass("active").removeClass("unactive");
    $(".odd").addClass("unactive").removeClass("active");
  });
  $(".odd").click(function () {
    $(".odd").addClass("active").removeClass("unactive");
    $(".even").addClass("unactive").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.unactive {background: #f99; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
.active {background: #99f; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some">
   <img id="1" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="2" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="3" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="4" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
<div class="some">
   <img id="5" class="pointer odd unactive" />
   <img id="6" class="pointer even active" />
</div>
```

Comment: OP said When I click img#3 I want to change other child (#1, #3, #4) to active

Comment: @YoYo Looks like OP has a mistake. Well, bleh. We'll ask OP.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan LoL. Thanks. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean you want to swap the current `active` and `inactive` elements, then you can just use `toggleClass()`. Try this:

```
$('.pointer').click(function() {
    $('.pointer').toggleClass('active unactive');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zxcobu9v/)